# only builtin utterances working ASK

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a skill in Amazon Alexa. I'm trying to test the same using echosim.io but the problem is as below.

My Skill name is **MyBot** and the same is invocation name.

In echosim.io, When I say *Alexa Launch MyBot*, it gives the welcome response (The help response that I've coded in). When I say *help*, it gives me the help response that I've entered.

I've 4 intents say

```
FaqIntentOne
FIntentOne
FaqIntentTwo
FIntentTwo
```

And my Sample utterances are as below.

```
FaqIntentOne what is first answer

FIntentOne give me first answer

FaqIntentTwo what is second answer

FIntentTwo give me second answer
```

When I run these, Alexa doesn't give me a response.

I've the correct methods and the correct response set there. please let me know why it is not working for the utterances other than the built in ones.

when test in Alexa's test interface in developer.amazon.com, it is giving me the correct response.
This is quite confusing.

Below is how it looks in my code.

```
if ("FaqIntentOne".equals(intentName) || "FIntentOne".equals(intentName)) {
return getFirstHelp(intent, session);
}
else if ("FaqIntentTwo".equals(intentName) || "FIntentTwo".equals(intentName)) {
return getSecondHelp(intent, session);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Amazon has referred people to echosim, it is not 'official' (it was developed by a 3rd party), so if it works in Amazon's test environment and not in echosim then it is possible that the issue is with echosim.

Otherwise I think you are going to need to look more closely at what is happening in your code, ie. debug it or put in some print statements and compare what happens when invoked in those 2 ways.

If you are running in Lambda - seems to be the most common - then you will need to take a look at CloudWatch logs.